# How to find "k" in system of equations?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

This is a $y^2=x^3+7$ elliptic curve points - $Q,G_1,G_2,G_3. k_1,k_2,k$? - secret exponents:

- $k_1*G_1( x_1,y_1) = Q(X,Y)$
- $k_2*G_2( x_2,y_2) = Q(X,Y)$
- $k*G_3( x_3,y_3) = Q(X,Y)$

How to find a $k$?" ??

$Q,G_1,G_2,G_3. k_1,k_2$ - are known

$k$? - need to find.

Comment: If no relations known about $k_1,k_2,k$ or $G_1, G_2, G_3$, then $[k]G_3=Q$ is independent and so it is generally hard to recover $k$. Unless the curve is weak, but this depends on the underlying field.

Comment: This question needs additional information on how these equations have arrived. This not an ordinary DLog.

Comment: Base points G1,G2 and secret exponents k1,k2 are bruteforced, G - information from property of a curve secp256k1.

Answer (score 2):

This is known:
$$k_1 \cdot G_1 = k_2 \cdot G_2 = k \cdot G_3 = Q$$

Additionally, let $G$ be a base point, such that we can have:

$$G_1 = k \cdot k_2 \cdot G$$
$$G_2 = k_1 \cdot k \cdot G$$
$$G_3 = k_1 \cdot k_2 \cdot G$$

This reduces to a case of tri-party Diffie-Hellman. So without further information, it's unsolvable.

Comment: What further information need for this ? Tnx for your comment @DannyNiu

Comment: I'm not sure what further information is needed, but if it's a question from a text book, there may be some context you missed to put here, or if there is no further context, then it's an error in the book.

Comment: how to find a k from  k_1*G_1=k_2*G_2=k*G_3=Q  ???

Comment: @Donald as I said in the answer, it reduces to a case of 3-party DH. You can't solve it without side information.

Comment: DannyNiu how I can add to this your answer https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/88141/81643    G = G_o*k_3 ? Because I don't know exact k for G, but I can get k_o for get G from (k_o * G_o=G) and this <>Q !!! ???

Comment: @Donald I'd add it for you if it adds meaningful content. But before that, I'd like to note that the additional equation is (as noted in the initial comment by Fractalic) independent, so it doesn't help extract useful information from the existing equations.

Comment: DannyNiu, add G=G_o*k_3 please If this not so hard for you ? Big thank you.